# Permisions issue on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, file-permissions

I'm developing a website on my local machine. The site has a file upload field which save the file to a location on my hard drive. Everything works well accept that IIS doesn't have permission to read the file so it won't display it back in the browser. If I go directly to the file and change it's permission (properties > security >allow full control) it works fine. How do I make all newly created file accessible by the system?

Answer (score 0):

you should have a look in the services snap in what is the uer under which the IIS service executes and add an ACL on his behalf to the folder of the uploaded files.

Comment: Thanks Alain. I'm a complete Windows noob. Whould you mind telling me how to do that or attaching a link?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you set the permissions on the folder instead and let the ACLs recurse?

Comment: Tried that, doesn't work

Comment: @Pardoner: It should work. Try [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) and filter on the event `ACCESS DENIED` and then surf to your page and look at the properties of the relevant `ACCESS DENIED` events to know the impersonator...